# Spring Security Keycloak Adapter cannot handle single sign-out when logout from another tab in browser

Tags: spring-boot, session, spring-security, keycloak, single-logout

I have implemented a spring boot web app using spring security and Keycloak to authenticate users based on [this tutorial](https://www.thomasvitale.com/spring-security-keycloak/). I used maven, spring boot 2.2.2 and Keycloak 8.0.1. All things works correctly except a problem in single sign-out. When I open the secured path of spring boot app in a tab of my browser (http://localhost:8080/books) and Keycloak account page (http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/{realm_name}/account) in another tab and login with one of the users in one of them, the other tab will aware of the login and after reload the page, that page will also be authenticated. But the problem is where, when both tabs are logged in and first I log out from account page, and reload spring boot app, the user remains active and the app does not aware of the log out action in other tabs. How can I handle this problem?

my project resource tree is like image below:
[Project resource tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KJrp.jpg)

**This is my *pom.xml* :**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sso</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>8.0.1</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Keycloak Adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-test-helper</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**This is *SecurityConfig.java* :**

```java
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    /**
     * Define an HttpSessionManager bean only if missing.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    /**
     * Define security constraints for the application resources.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/books").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/manager").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
}
```

**This is *LibraryController.java* :**

```java
@Controller
public class LibraryController {
    private final HttpServletRequest request;
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LibraryController(HttpServletRequest request, BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.request = request;
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String getHome() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/books")
    public String getBooks(Model model) {
        configCommonAttributes(model);
        model.addAttribute("books", bookRepository.readAll());
        return "books";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/manager")
    public String getManager(Model model) {
        configCommonAttributes(model);
        model.addAttribute("books", bookRepository.readAll());
        return "manager";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/logout")
    public String logout() throws ServletException {
        request.logout();
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    private void configCommonAttributes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("firstname", getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken().getGivenName());
        model.addAttribute("lastname", getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken().getFamilyName());
        model.addAttribute("email", getKeycloakSecurityContext().getIdToken().getEmail());
    }

    /**
     * The KeycloakSecurityContext provides access to several pieces of information
     * contained in the security token, such as user profile information.
     */
    private KeycloakSecurityContext getKeycloakSecurityContext() {
        return (KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
    }
}
```

and below is my ***DemoappApplication.java* :**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can help with this problem?

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this problem yet. Has no one had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just solved by setting the base URL of my spring boot application as `Admin-URL` in the corresponding client configuration page of Keycloak server (admin console). Now, the spring boot app is aware of user log out from other apps.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue but adding Admin-URL does not solve it. Can you show me some examples?

Comment: not working for me, I need to some examples on keycloak:19

Comment: I think many things have been changed since Keycloak 15 and they have migrated to Quarkus distribution. So, I'm not sure if this solution will work for newer versions. But on Keycloak <= 8.0.1 it solved the issue.